# Что тут написано?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите разобраться, в коде JS + JQuery встретил вот такую строку:

```js
const itemHasInOriginalSelectedList =
    _thisEl.$.children('[value="' + isnOfItem + '"]').length > 0
```

Не могу понять, что тут происходит, может кто-нибудь подробно разъяснить?

Comment: Вкратце - ищутся потомки элемента по какому-то параметру и проверяется, что такие потомки вообще есть в наличии (что их больше 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понимаю, то:

- `_thisEl` - это ссылка на некий элемент
- `_thisEl.$` - это обёртка над `_thisEl`, которая возвращает такой объект, что у него есть метод `children`, который позволят достать список всех дочерних элементов по селектору (вот тут не могу точно сказать дочерних элементов какого уровня, либо первого либо любого)
- `_thisEl.$.children('[value="' + isnOfItem + '"]')` - это все те дочерние элементы, у которых в аттрибуте `value` стоит значение `isnOfItem`
- `_thisEl.$.children('[value="' + isnOfItem + '"]').length` - ну это очевидно возвращает кол-во таких элементов
- `_thisEl.$.children('[value="' + isnOfItem + '"]').length > 0` - проверяем есть ли вообще хоть один такой элемент